# Is there a way to make many copies of a spreadsheet file and choose the name for each file in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So, as of now, I have the below function that definitely works to make as many copies of a Google Sheets as possible. For ex, below will make 3 copies of a Google Sheets (in reality, I'll want to make 40+ copies).

What I'm having trouble with is finding a way to automatically change their file names, so that it's each person's name and then " - System" for each copy.

This is what I currently have:

```
    function copyDocs() {
        for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        var drive=DriveApp.getFileById('SheetsID');
        drive.makeCopy();
  }
}
```

I'd want to do something like this:

```
var people = Array("Johnson Henry", "Person Last", "Tierra Smith")

function copyDocs() {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){ 
    var drive=DriveApp.getFileById('SheetsID');
    drive.makeCopy(people[i] & " - System");
  }
}
```

Do any of you know of a way to modify my code to do this? Note that I'm a beginner at Apps Script, so please forgive my lack of knowledge here.

Comment: Was there a error thrown on your attempt?

Comment: I thought he had an error, but he issue is this: `below will make 3 copies of a Google Sheets (in reality, I'll want to make 40+ copies).` I believe he just wants to use the length of the array instead of a hardcopy `3`.  @TheMaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a more efficient way.

You can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the elements of the `people` array and then use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to name the files accordingly:

```
function copyDocs() { 
  
  const drive=DriveApp.getFileById('SpreadsheetID');
  const people = ["Johnson Henry", "Person Last", "Tierra Smith"];
 
  people.forEach(person=>{
    var copy = drive.makeCopy( `${person} - System`)
    var copySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy.getId());
    var copySheet = copySpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    copySheet.getRange('B2').setValue(person);
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Marios! Do you also know if there's a way for me to change a particular cell to each person's name (e.g., I'd want cell B2 = each person's name)? I thought I'd be able to figure this out on my own.

Comment: @vvquiuno I edited my answer. But please any further follow-up questions should be asked in a separate post. Please post a new question if you have further issues.

Comment: @vvquiuno in my updated solution, `getSheets()[0]` indicates that only the first sheet will have the name of the person at cell B2. If you want the second sheet then say `getSheets()[1]`. If you want all of them, then you need to iterate through all of them again with a forEach loop. But all of these modifications should be asked in a different post.

Comment: Thank you so much, Marios! This solution works for me, but I'll definitely post in another comment if anything else pops up.